# When I clicked menu button in navbar button page freezes and crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

When I click on the menu icon in the navbar, which allows me to set a state, the page completely freezes and crashes.

If I use useState(true) the menu becomes visible without any problem.
So does useState(false).

I tried useCallback and useEffect. When I tried useEffect, the menu opened when I refreshed the page, but in this way, I could not manage the menu with a button. When I tried useCallback I got the same error with useState.

*Please help I lost my youth*

Code:

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
 import {Menu} from '@mui/icons-material';
 function Navbar() {

 const [menuClicked, setMenuClicked] = useState(false);

 const updateMenu = () => {
    setMenuClicked(!menuClicked)
 }
 return(
  <div className='h-16 z-20 relative'>
        <div className='fixed top-0 text-left text-6xl font-bold items-center bg-white/40  h-20 w-full flex dark:text-white dark:bg-neutral-900/40'>
            <div className='flex flex-1 items-center pb-5'>
                <span className='pl-4'>psue</span>
            </div>

            <div className='flex justify-end w-7/12 scale-0 md:scale-100 items-center'>
                <ul className='flex text-xl gap-12 pb-0'>
                    <li className=''>
                        <a href='/'>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='/livechat'>Live Chat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        {checkLogin ? (<a href='/profile'>{auth.currentUser.email.substring(0, auth.currentUser.email.indexOf('@'))}</a>) : (<a onClick={signOutFunction} href='/login'>Login</a>)}
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div className='z-20 pr-5 pb-5 scale-150 overflow-x-hidden md:scale-0'>
                <Menu onClick={() => updateMenu()} className='cursor-pointer'/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div className={menuClicked ? 'translate-x-0 transition fixed bottom-0 top-0 right-0 h-screen w-64 z-10' : 'transition translate-x-72 fixed top-0 right-0 h-screen w-0'}>
          <div className='bg-white/30 dark:bg-neutral-900/30 dark:text-white fixed right-0 top-0 w-full h-full'>
              <ul className='flex flex-col text-xl gap-16 h-full w-full justify-center items-center backdrop-blur-lg font-bold'>
                  <li>
                    <CloseIcon onClick={() => updateMenu()} className='cursor-pointer scale-150 fixed top-24'/>
                  </li>
                  <li className=''>
                        <a href='/'>Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='/livechat'>Live Chat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        {checkLogin ? (<a href='/profile'>{auth.currentUser.email.substring(0, auth.currentUser.email.indexOf('@'))}</a>) : (<a onClick={signOutFunction} href='/login'>Login</a>)}
                    </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: why do you want to use `setMenuClicked(!menuClicked)`? also, why are you showing both buttons at the same time? wouldn't it be better if you used `menuClicked` to make  a conditional to show only one icon based on the state?

Comment: There's a `</div>` tag missing for `<div className='h-16 z-20 relative'>`, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @mocherfaoui I'm using setMenuClicked(!menuClicked) because I want to be able to turn it on and off using the same state also I'don't show both button at same time look that ` {menuClicked ? 'translate-x-0 transition fixed bottom-0 top-0 right-0 h-screen w-64 z-10' : 'transition translate-x-72 fixed top-0 right-0 h-screen w-0'} `

Comment: @LucasSurdiFranco thanks thats my wrong I missed it while passing the code here but I don't have this error in my own file so unfortunately this is not the solution to my problem but thank you.